# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit) : variable lengths differ

Tags: r, random-forest, spatial, predict, r-raster

I know this has been asked before but none of the troubleshooting methods I've found have worked.
I'm running a random forest to spatially predict the distribution of sediment grain size in an area.

```
sed$mud <- sed$mud/100
sed$sand <- sed$sand/100
sed$gravel <- sed$gravel/100
sed <- sed[complete.cases(sed),]
#model grain size composition using random forest
rfm <- randomForest(mud ~ . - sand - gravel, sed, na.action=na.omit)
rfs <- randomForest(sand ~ . - mud - gravel, sed, na.action=na.omit)
rfg <- randomForest(gravel ~ . - mud - sand, sed, na.action=na.omit)
gravel <- sed$gravel
sand <- sed$sand
mud <- sed$mud
#make predictions over study area
  #load rasters and make a raster stack
bath <- raster("220701_bathymetry.tif")
bbpi <- mask(resample(raster("220701_stbbpi.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
east <- mask(resample(raster("220701_east.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
fbpi <- mask(resample(raster("220701_stfbpi.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
north <- mask(resample(raster("220701_north.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
curd <- mask(resample(raster("220701_currentdir.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
curm <- mask(resample(raster("220701_currentmag.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
rug <- mask(resample(raster("220701_ruggedness.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
slope <- mask(resample(raster("220701_slope.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
umean <- mask(resample(raster("220701_ustarmean.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
umax <- mask(resample(raster("220701_ustarmax.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
wmax <- mask(resample(raster("220701_wavemax.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
wmean <- mask(resample(raster("220701_wavemean.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
edm <- mask(resample(raster("220701_ED_mainland.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
edi <- mask(resample(raster("220701_ED_islands.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
mean <- mask(resample(raster("bathy_mean_extract.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
stdev <- mask(resample(raster("bathy_stdev_extract.tif"),bath), mask=bath)
var <- mask(resample(raster("bathy_variance_extract.tif"),bath), mask=bath)

rfstack <- stack(bath,bbpi,east,fbpi,north,curd,curm,rug,slope,umean,umax,wmax,wmean,edm,edi,mean,stdev,var)
names(rfstack) <- c("bathymetry","bbpi","eastness","fbpi","northness","current_direction","current_magnitude","ruggedness","slope","ustarmean",
                    "ustarmax","maxwavepow","meanwavepow","ED_mainland","ED_islands","bathy_mean","bathy_stdev","bathy_var")
#use the random forest over the study area
mud_pred <- raster::predict(rfstack,model=rfm)
sand_pred <- raster::predict(rfstack,model=rfs)
gravel_pred <- raster::predict(rfstack,model=rfg)
```

Trying to run raster::predict always gives me the same error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'current_direction')
```

How do I fix this error? I was using an older version of R to run the same code and never had any problems. I'm only getting this error after updating to the latest version of R. I don't want to go back to an earlier version of R because I have other code that will stop working if I do that.

Comment: Hi Emily, I have run into that error before, and it usually arises if the names in the rasterstack of predictors don't exactly match the column names of predictor in the random forest model.  I think I can solve the issue for you if you could provide the output of `rfm$terms`, `rfs$terms`, and `rfg$terms`.  Also if you could make a simple reproducible example, that would be extraordinarily helpful